# Is It Possible to Produce Old French Drop Caps Like These with Latex?

Tags: french, lettrine, drop-cap

I have come across these drop caps a book published in 1883 in Lyon, France---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to produce these drop caps such as these with Latex? I have not been able to find them available anywhere.

Comment: Look at `lettrine` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine with the option `image`. Look also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-can-i-create-documents-in-latex-using-a-calligraphic-first-letter-for-chapte

Comment: For the ornament, look at `pgfornament` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210243/ornament-drop-caps-effect?rq=1.

Comment: Not very close, but you may like [1585 Flowery](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/1585-flowery-font-glc) (commercial).

Comment: Also see [briar press](https://www.briarpress.org/cuts/browse?t=19) for initial caps to use as images.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you very much for your helpful comments and links.

Comment: @Thérèse Many thanks for your helpful comments, and for providing the link to Briar press.

Comment: @jean-marie You're welcome!